# Get all subclasses of UIView in runtime in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Is is possible in Objective-c runtime to get an array of all subclasses of UIView class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code that prints names of all UIView subclasses: (How to get list of all classes available at runtime can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_getClassList)). Note also that this code will print only direct `UIView` subclasses, if you want to go further down the hierarchy you'll probably need to call listed code recursively with desired superclass as a parameter.

```
Class * classes = NULL;
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

if (numClasses > 0 )
{
    classes = malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);

    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; ++i){
        if (class_getSuperclass(classes[i]) == [UIView class]){
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(classes[i]));
        }
    }

    free(classes);
}
```

Comment: @Yuji : you can use Recursion to find all subclasses, it looks like finding all subfolders of 1 folder

Comment: For those looking for a way to loop through a class hierarchy, I've written a [Class Hierarchy Logger](https://github.com/sebaven/class-hierarchy-logger) that uses a similar approach. It might be useful if someone needs more insight on how to iterate the subclass hierarchy. I hope it helps!